# Syntax error when using sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm using the following code:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("Quiz.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,);
''')
```

This produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yoshi/Documents/PYTHON/Database.py", line 15, in <module>
    ''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "username": syntax error
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: there is a `,` missing just before username.

Comment: And that error comes from the database, it's not a Python error.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot a comma in the line before username

```
userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
```